# getting client server to work in android, should I use a different IP address?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, client

I am using the following code that I got from a website to set up client server in android.  one Android tablet is running the server code and another Android tablet is running the client code.  The code is pasted in exactly and should work as it does work for other people, however I can't get it to work in my case. Both tablets are connected to wifi

There are two reasons that people tell me why it is not working. One reason mentioned is that I have to set port forwarding on my router, and the other reason often mentioned is that I have to set a different IP address in the server code.  But I don't know what IP address to set.

Any Ideas?

Server code

```
 public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

// default ip
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// designate a port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // do whatever you want to the front end
                                    // this is where you can be creative
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// gets the ip address of your phone's network
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

 }
```

client code

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText serverIp;

    private Button connectPhones;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    private boolean connected = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.client);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
        connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
                if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
                connected = true;
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);
                            // where you issue the commands
                            out.println("Hey Server!");
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
     }
```

logcat output

```
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): C: Error
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.15 (port 8080): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at com.example.client.ClientActivity$ClientThread.run(ClientActivity.java:60)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
```

Comment: if there is a static ip setting in the Table, not let the router give your Tablet a dynamic ip.

Comment: i will try that and see what happens

Comment: The server must have a Static ip. I dont think you need to do any "port forward" as long as your inside your LAN. Your tablets will be seen as a computer or a printer. That's my experiance. Change server port to 36358 or 56001 to test it

Comment: i will try that but what should i use for my IP address?  public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.001";

Comment: for the server use public static String SERVERIP = "localhost"

Comment: Now, setup up static ip in your Tablet, read [this](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/le-pan-development/33709-setting-up-static-ip-fixed-ip-address-setting-no-dhcp-le-pans.html) and you'll get the hang of it. If that is not your Tablet! Google your Tablet model to set up this

Comment: i googled this and found out how.  change from DHCP to static,  now should i do this for both the tablets?   client and server ones?

Comment: i just set both tablets to static IP address   first tablet IP address 192.168.11.1 and second tablet 192.168.11.22  and both of the tablets use the same gateway address 192.168.11.1

Comment: both tablets are inside my LAN.  both use the same wifi router to connect to the internet

Comment: Yea having static ip's is good i think. This way you always know who is who also if you need to control and set bandwidth level in your router you can identify devices in your lan. There's a better way to do this. In your router (if it exist in your brand) you can control this. Your router assign ip adress to a specific device. It does this by pairing mac address to static ip